# How to provide parserLib and inferSchema options together for spark-csv

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema","true").option("parserLib", "UNIVOCITY").option("escape","\"").load("file.csv")
```

When I create dataframe using above code I am getting following error:

> ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   com.databricks.spark.csv.readers.BulkCsvReader.aggregate(Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/Function2;Lscala/Function2;)Ljava/lang/Object;

If I avoid parseLib option It runs fine.
I want to set spark-csv parser to Univocity and at the same time datatype should be recognised by spark csv using inferSchema.

Note: I am using spark-csv 1.3 (its not working for any version of it)
Spark: 1.6.2
Scala : 2.10.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it resolved.
But i found workaround that define schema externally and read csv using 'univocity' parser.